# Eloquent select field after aggregation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have three models, `User`, `Post` and `Comment`. `User` and `Post` are in a One-To-Many relationship, and so are `User` and `Comment`. For the sake of this example, **there isn't** a `Post`-`Comment` relationship.

When I run the following query

```
User::withCount(['posts', 'comments'])->get()
```

I obtain the expected results:

```
[
...
  App\Models\User {#3459
    id: 18,
    username: "Foo",
    created_at: "2021-12-08 11:38:39",
    updated_at: "2021-12-08 11:38:39",
    posts_count: 5,
    comments_count: 15,
  }
...
]
```

I would like to remove the timestamps from the resulting models.
I've tried putting the array of fields I want as parameter for `get` (as in `->get(['username', 'posts_count', 'comments_count'])`, but the result didn't change at all.

I've also tried replacing `get(...)` with `select(...)->get()`, but that produces this error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 
'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'posts_count' in 'field list'  
(SQL: select `username`, `posts_count`, `comments_count` from `users`)'
```

which I assume it is due to the fact that the aggregation function is not yet being executed.

So I came up with this solution

```
$usersWithCounts = User::withCount(['posts', 'comments'])->get()
    ->map(function ($item, $key) {
         return $item->only(['username', 'posts_count', 'comments_count']); 
      });
```

but it doesn't feel right: the returned collection is no longer made of Eloquent models, just simple arrays.

```
[
...
  [
    username: "Foo",
    posts_count: 5,
    comments_count: 15,
  ]
...
]
```

What's the right way of proceeding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code may suite your needs:

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know I can hide those fields with the `$hidden` property, but what if I want to exclude them just for this query and not all of them?

Comment: Can you try this approach `User::withCount(['posts', 'comments'])->makeHidden(['created_at', 'updated_at'])->get()` ?

Comment: Didn't know of the `makeHidden` method! Works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You definitely use above approach filter collection data. Another way you also use forget() of collection that remove value from collection using key.

For More information refer below link

[Forgot collection method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-forget)

Comment: `User::withCount(['posts', 'comments'])->get()->forget(['created_at', 'updated_at'])` doesn't produce the result I expect. Can you provide an example on how it should be used?

Comment: It's working fine for me . I use same syntax like $collection->forget(['number','object']); You can check it on below following link https://collection-playground.atymic.dev/

Comment: You can use filter function also like 

$users = User::withCount(['posts', 'comments'])->get();
$results = $users->filter(function($value, $key) {
    return $key != 'created_at' && $key != 'updated_at';
});